# I'm trying to import the Stripe API using pip but I'm getting a module not found error even though I've installed it

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to install stripe using pip, however, when I try to run my project with the import I get a module not found error. This makes no sense to me as when I look at the list of requirements I see stripe: 5.2.0. I'm using Django and I'm trying to install it in my virtual environment. The stack trace is shown below:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bench\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\bench\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\z12_server\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('payments/', include('payment_processing_app.urls')),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\payment_processing_app\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\z12-app\server\payment_processing_app\views.py", line 10, in <module>
    import stripe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
```

This is how I'm trying to use it:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key

try:
  charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount = total_amount,
    currency = 'eur',
    source = {
      'object': 'card',
      'number': card_number,
      'exp_month': expiry_month,
      'exp_year': expiry_year,
      'cvc': cvv
    },
    description = title
  )
except Exception as e:
  print('Error: ', e)
```

Comment: What's the exact command you used to install the stripe module? Do you see stripe listed when you run `pip list`?

Comment: The error shown is just on trying to run the code with stripe called, no indication of it was installed. To be clear, are you certain you have stripe installed with pip in the correct environment and that your code is currently running in that environment?

Comment: Yes, I can see it listed when I run `pip list` and when I try to run `pip install stripe` when my virtual environment is activated, I get messages saying "requirements already met". So as far as I can see, it is installed in the environment

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling and toying around, the best solution I could come up with to resolve this is to run the command:

```
python -m pip install stripe
```

Not sure if this is the best solution but it has resolved my issue.